# Be able to write dynamic text to image src with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have earlier posted a question where I wanted to change image names on the fly, but now after a lot of thoughts, I would like to just be able to add some text to a image name, keeping the original image name.

I have searched Google and here, and tried what I've found, but unfortunately I haven't made it work, so I hope someone can guide/help me on the way.

Through mod_rewrite in .htaccess I would like to make a rule that makes it possible to insert dynamic text before the image name making the image name more SEO "friendly" - from what I've found I need the text and image name separated by an identifier, e.g. "---".

Example:
Original path and image name: 
`<img src="/images/testimage.jpg" />`

Image with dynamic text separated by an identifier: 
`<img src="/images/this-is-dynamic-text---testimage.jpg" />`

I have mod_rewrite in my URL structure, so the URL looks nicer - this taken into consideration, the mod_rewrite for the images should be working in all "folders".
My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ index.php?country=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([A-Яа-я-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ index.php?country=$1&id=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ index.php?country=$1&subid=$5&id=$4
```

The image name mod_rewrite that I have tried, but failed with, looks like this:
`RewriteRule ^(/.+?)---.+$ /$1.jpg [L,NC]`

When done I of course would like it to work on all images (jpg, gif, png).

I really hope someone can guide me on my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule for images:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /kuhlmann/

RewriteRule ^.+?---(.+)$ $1 [L,NE]
```

Leading slash is not matched when rule is used inside .htaccess.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the rule does not work for me, when I paste it in my .htaccess file. I have pastet it in, and tried it out by editing an img src from this: `<img src="<?=$linkpath?>images/forside-pic.jpg" width="700" />` to this `<img src="<?=$linkpath?>images/this-is-dynamic-text---forside-pic.jpg" width="700" />` When trying a broken image link is created. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure if my comment automatically notified you @anubhava so for safety, I write this comment. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have tried the updated rule, but unfortunately it still does not work @anubhava - I have a link here []http://www.mazey.dk/kuhlmann/index_good.html where I have a image with dynamic text and and one without, but it's only the one without that works: `<img src="dynamic-text---elheat.jpg" alt="image with dynamic text" />
<img src="elheat.jpg" alt="image without dynamic text" />
` Just for information, I have placed the .htaccess file inside the folder 'kuhlmann' - this is done because that makes it easier for me to develop isolated before activation in the root on the "real" domain.

Comment: Ah you didn't tell me about `kuhlmann` folder earlier. See updated rule for `/kuhlmann/.htaccess`

Comment: Sorry about that @anubhava - When I design I always have everything placed in a folder on my own domain, and when I'm done, I put it all live on the respective domain. How will this RewriteBase affect the other rules I have? 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ index.php?country=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([A-Яа-я-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ index.php?country=$1&id=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ index.php?country=$1&subid=$5&id=$4 RewriteBase /kuhlmann/

RewriteRule ^.+?---(.+)$ $1 [L,NE]`

Comment: But I can tell you that this works - just great! I sincerely thank you with the help and your expertise @anubhava! I placed the RewriteBase just under the other rules, so the only rule below is the one with the images, and this works like a charm!

Comment: Just to spam you some more - does this only work in the root of that folder? I have a clean written URL, where it does not work http://mazey.dk/kuhlmann/dk/elvarme/elpatroner-120/2/7.php Am I missing something? :-)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. When you move to root .htaccess just change it to `RewriteBase /`.

Comment: Weird - it works with the html file in the root, and it works with this URL http://mazey.dk/kuhlmann/dk/elvarme/2.php but when I go another step further with this URL http://mazey.dk/kuhlmann/dk/elvarme/elpatroner-110/2/6.php it stops working - it's like the folder structure that has been written perhaps influences and makes the image rule stop working? Would be awesome having it working no matter what URL in /kuhlmann/ you are... Will you look at it one last time @anubhava?

Comment: Ahhh... I think I know why @anubhava - the rule (I think) only links to images in the root folder /kuhlmann/ I have 1 image there, that I used to test and that worked in the HTML file and in the first link in the above comment, but all images when working are placed in /kuhlmann/images/

Comment: Yes that sounds right. You can use Chrome Developer Tool's Net tab to see what is the requested image URL and trap all these 404 causing ones.

Comment: Thanks - did that, and figured that in the rule I could add the images folder, so it points correctly, like this: `RewriteBase /kuhlmann/
RewriteRule ^.+?---(.+)$ images/$1 [L,NE]` This works great! Thanks again @anibhava - I hope I'm not to big of a pain, but a quick question more, and I'll leave you alone and thank you more, but if you look at all my rules, as you can see in the above comments, I have made better looking URL's but this has created a bit of a problem, because now I can't access an existing folder "admin" because the rule overrules the "real" folders - any idea to access this?

Comment: All of your rules in question have `\.php` in the end that will not affect `admin` folder.